# Start the wizard not working in SharePoint Server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation, configuration-wizard

I am installing SharePoint Server 2013, I started configuring the farm. However, when I clicked on Configuration Wizards, It asks me 'How do you want to configure your SharePoint farm?' I want to click on Start the Wizard, but I am not redirected to anything.
Does anyone knows why, please?

[image]